# How to check either current viewcontroller is pushed or presented

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin. I have searched a lot to know either my ViewController is pushed or presented. So I will pop it or dismiss it accordingly, but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check if the current viewcontroller exists in **Navigation Stack**.

#### Solution

```
if(this.NavigationController == null)
{
    this.DismissViewController(true, null);
}
else
{
    this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be used below method

```
private static UIViewController GetController()

{
    var vc = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
    while (vc.PresentedViewController != null  && vc.PresentedViewController.ToString().Contains("Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ModalWrapper"))
        vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
    return vc;
}
```

If it’s return not null then that’s mean you have Present controller in stacks